How do you know if this tire's patch is perfectly done?
How do you know if patch in the tyre hole is a good one? What are we need to check? This is good as new? Tyre is good as where there is no puncture before it? Thanks!


Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Unfortunately, after being punctured, the tire will never be as "good" as it was before the puncture. That's because at some level there is damage to the inside structure of the tire (ie: the belts may suffer damage). However, that doesn't mean they aren't serviceable. It just means some form of damage may have occurred.
As for how to tell if the patch job was done correctly, the easy litmus is does the tire hold air. If so, it was done correctly. Usually, inside tire repairs are pretty hard to screw up. The tire patch is bonded with glue and/or heat to keep it from leaking. Tire shops have been using this type of repair for quite some time. They are tried and true and work very well.

Gives me an inference that it is far to superior than a plug one?

@TheOne - Yes, they are better than a plug one. The patch works almost every time (I'd say "every time", but there are those weird instances). A plug can fail to seal, but works most of the time (if applied correctly). They can fail to work a lot more often than a patch, that's for sure. The big thing about a plug is, they can easily be done at home. A patch requires you unseat at least one of the two beads to open access to the inside of the tire. This requires a tire machine to make it happen which most people do not have at home.

Disagree with the answer above. Holding air is easy - chewing gum or silicon would do this. Holding air alone is not an indicator of a correct repair.
There is no way of knowing if the repair is good unless it was analysed destructively (cut apart) or scanned with an ultrasonic machine. There is a lot of trust put upon a mechanic for many tasks and this is one of them.
A 'proper' repair is usually made up of a plug and a patch that looks a bit like a mushroom, known as a combi-plug, It also requires the right glue which vulcanises the rubber surface to bind the two rubber parts as one.
The plug is necessary to fill the hole and stop water wicking into the steel wire band and corroding (between the layers of rubber). This is one of the main reasons for tyres delaminating and being strewn all over the highway.
But, a proper repair takes time and uses some expensive parts (compared to a simple patch). You get what you pay for.
